# Using wildcard in xpath search

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have the following element on a page, which I'm using xpath to locate;

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
```

What I'd like to do is test that the **content** part of the element contains **"noindex"**, and ignore the **"follow"** part of the element.

Previously I've used **css** to test this kind of thing using something along the lines of **content*="noindex"**, but because of this particular page structure I'm not able to use css.

So (css) `head > meta:nth-child(60)[content*="noindex"]` works (but this is inflexible as the element location can change) but (xpath) `//meta[@name="robots" and @content*="noindex"]`doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the  below xpath.

```
//meta[@name="robots"][contains(@content,"noindex")]
```

If you want to use `starts-with` below is the syntax.

```
//meta[@name="robots"][starts-with(@content,"noindex")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a particular version of XPath: from XPath 2.0 you can use regular expressions. For example

```
//meta[@name="robots"][tokenize(@content, ",") = "noindex"]
```

If you want to do this in the browser you'll need to install a third-party XPath library such as Saxon-JS.